# How to skip reserved unicode characters in a auto generated unicode character range in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I have written a perl program to autogenerate a range of unicode characters in perl.

```
#!/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use open qw/:std :encoding(UTF-8)/;

my ($beg, $end, $start, $finish, @chars);

print "Enter the beginning Unicode value of your Language's script: ";
chomp( $beg = <> );

print "Enter the last Unicode value of your Language's script: ";
chomp( $end = <> );

$beg =~ s/U\+(.*)/$1/;
$end =~ s/U\+(.*)/$1/;

$start  = hex($beg);
$finish = hex($end);

@chars = ( $start .. $finish );

foreach (@chars) {

    my $char = chr($_);

    next unless ($char);

    print "$char\n";
}
```

On running this script using values `U+0B80` and `U+0BFF` my output is:

> ஀  ஁  ஂ  ஃ  ஄  அ  ஆ  இ  ஈ  உ  ஊ  ஋  ஌  ஍  எ  ஏ  ஐ  ஑  ஒ  ஓ  ஔ  க  ஖  ஗
>   ஘  ங  ச  ஛  ஜ  ஝  ஞ  ட  ஠  ஡  ஢  ண  த  ஥  ஦  ஧  ந  ன  ப  ஫  ஬  ஭  ம  ய
>   ர  ற  ல  ள  ழ  வ  ஶ  ஷ  ஸ  ஹ  ஺  ஻  ஼  ஽  ா  ி  ீ  ு  ூ  ௃  ௄  ௅  ெ  ே
>   ை  ௉  ொ  ோ  ௌ  ்  ௎  ௏  ௐ  ௑  ௒  ௓  ௔  ௕  ௖  ௗ  ௘  ௙  ௚  ௛  ௜  ௝  ௞  ௟
>   ௠  ௡  ௢  ௣  ௤  ௥  ௦  ௧  ௨  ௩  ௪  ௫  ௬  ௭  ௮  ௯  ௰  ௱  ௲  ௳  ௴  ௵  ௶  ௷
>   ௸  ௹  ௺  ௻  ௼  ௽  ௾  ௿

All those box characters are reserved spaces in Unicode Block.

I want to remove all such reserved spaces. Is there a way to do this in perl?

The line `next unless($char)` does not seem to do the trick as even reserved space seems to have a value (the box character).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to print only visible characters.see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

```
next unless ($char=~/[[:print:]]/);
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems you need the Unassigned category:

```
next if $char =~ /\p{Unassigned}/;
# Or shorter:
next if $char =~ /\p{Cn}/;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [pragma `charnames`](http://perldoc.perl.org/charnames.html).

```
use charnames ();
use open qw/:std :encoding(UTF-8)/;

foreach (hex 'B80' .. hex 'B83' ) {
    next unless charnames::viacode($_);
    print chr $_;
}
```

Output:

```
ஂஃ
```

When you remove the `next`, it will be:

```
஀஁ஂஃ
```

---

**Update:** I did a Benchmark of the three techniques used in [Arunesh's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32123859/1331451), [choroba's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32123672/1331451) and my answer. `charnames` obviously lost quite badly.

```
use charnames ();
use open qw/:std :encoding(UTF-8)/;
use Benchmark ':all';

cmpthese(
    '-2',
    {
        'charnames' => sub {
            foreach ( hex 'B80' .. hex 'BFF' ) {
                next unless charnames::viacode($_);
            }
        },
        'posix' => sub {
            foreach ( hex 'B80' .. hex 'BFF' ) {
                next unless ( chr($_) =~ /[[:print:]]/ );
            }
        },
        'unassigned' => sub {
            foreach ( hex 'B80' .. hex 'BFF' ) {
                next if ( chr($_) =~ /\p{Cn}/ );
            }
        },
    }
);

__END__
              Rate  charnames      posix unassigned
charnames   28.4/s         --      -100%      -100%
posix      27115/s     95239%         --       -14%
unassigned 31656/s    111205%        17%         --
```

Comment: I strongly advice against using this technique. The benchmark is quite clear. But I'll leave it because it's a feature I didn't know about, and corelist says it's been there since Perl 5.6.0.

Comment: Also note that _posix_ and _unassigned_ are pretty equal if the benchmark is run several times.

Comment: if you just want to use charnames::viacode or charnames::vianame do `use charnames ();`